# magmi product import problem

Tags: magento-1.9, import, magmi

[image]

I imported the csv file named `magmi.csv` which is new one containing only 3 rows. But,the magmi importer imports from previous `magmi.csv` file which had 624 rows.
What might be the issue on this. Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: try renaming `magmi.csv` to `magmi1.csv` & upload......

Comment: I just wanna to know, if i put nothing inside directory /var/import, still it imports from magmi.csv which doesn't even exists.

Comment: magmi.csv may exists in some other folder , check under `magmi/var/import` folder once..... check  `CSVs base directory` which is displaying in magmi page.... it will show from which folder .csv file will import.....

Comment: The problem i found out was, i need to save global parameter each time i change the csv filename. Now it tries to import the correct csv as i provided. But the problem i faced is it says : SKU A30412 - cannot create product sku:A30412, no attribute_set defined

Comment: looks like `attribute set` is not matching in backend & in excel sheet.......